# 1980's (probably) TV fantasy setting (live action) where a bow(s) bound itself to its user by branding something on their chest

Tags: story-identification, tv

This could've been a tv series, made for tv movie, mini-series, or a movie from theater on tv. It was live-action fantasy. The good guys (I think) had a bow(s) that would bind itself to its user by zapping them on the chest and would scar/brand some sort of pattern there.

Answer (score 7):

I think you probably mean [The Archer: Fugitive from the Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Archer:_Fugitive_from_the_Empire) a failed TV pilot from 1981.

YouTube has the trailer and you can see the "branding" if you go to 1:00.

Comment: This looks amazing! How many series did it run for?

Comment: @Valorum Just the one movie on TV.  Never got picked up to series.  Left on a cliffhanger, too.

Comment: Agreed.   I remember watching this pilot as a little kid.  It's almost certainly the show the OP is looking for.